# mysql query to average values every hour

Tags: mysql, database, union, average

The following query grabs the temperature, outside temperature, ph and total suspended solids from my aquarium database and displays it in 1 table shown below. each of the values is stored in its own table and is being logged every minute.

I would like to change the query below to be able to get the average value for each hour instead of displaying the value stored in the database at x hour:00:00.

Please help

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timeTable.minuteTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') time,
oT2.temperature temperature,
T2.temperature temp,
S2.solids solids,
P2.Ph Ph
FROM
(
    SELECT minuteTime.minuteTime minuteTime,
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM outside_temperature WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) otempTime, 
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM temperature1 WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) tempTime, 
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM Ph WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) phTime,  
    ( SELECT MAX(time) FROM solids WHERE time <= minuteTime.minuteTime AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) solidsTime

    FROM  
    (
        SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 2 * 2) HOUR minuteTime
        FROM Ph
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 2 * 2) HOUR
        FROM solids
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 2 * 2) HOUR
        FROM outside_temperature
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        UNION SELECT DATE(time) + INTERVAL (HOUR(time) DIV 2 * 2) HOUR
        FROM temperature1
        WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND time <= NOW()
        GROUP BY 1
    ) minuteTime
) timeTable
LEFT JOIN outside_temperature oT2 ON oT2.time = timeTable.otempTime
LEFT JOIN temperature1 T2 ON T2.time = timeTable.tempTime
LEFT JOIN solids S2 ON S2.time = timeTable.solidsTime
LEFT JOIN Ph P2 ON P2.time = timeTable.phTime
ORDER BY minuteTime ASC
```

This is the result of the query

```
2013-04-03 22:00    27.12   26.06   139 7.54
2013-04-04 0:00     27.06   26      142 7.54
2013-04-04 2:00     26.94   26      142 7.5
2013-04-04 4:00     26.87   25.94   142 7.5
2013-04-04 6:00     26.75   25.87   141 7.58
2013-04-04 8:00     26.87   25.87   141 7.58
2013-04-04 10:00    26.87   25.87   141 7.58
2013-04-04 12:00    26.87   25.87   141 7.58
2013-04-04 14:00    26.69   25.87   144 7.54
2013-04-04 16:00    26.56   25.81   144 7.58
2013-04-04 18:00    26.5    25.75   144 7.61
2013-04-04 20:00    26.81   25.75   144 7.43
```

Comment: So many nested selects... my lunch is coming back up

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timeTable.minuteTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') time,
AVG(oT2.temperature) temperature,
AVG(T2.temperature) temp,
AVG(S2.solids) solids,
AVG(P2.Ph) Ph
......./*YOUR QUERY
--AT THE LAST
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timeTable.minuteTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')
```

Comment: your query is still doing the same as my query. I would like a query that first gets the average for an hour from the 60 individual values in my database and then display this average for each hour for all the other sensors, i.e. ph temperature solids and outside temperature

Comment: the query should be using something like SELECT DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
     , AVG(x.Ph) avg_Ph
  FROM Ph x where time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(x.time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');